# Apache2 - page does not render

Tags: apache, apache2

I recently deleted all of my Virual Host set ups on Apache to do some restructuring and now that I have everything back together whenever I visit a url to my server a windows explorer "save as" window opens instead of the page rendering. I'm not sure what I did differently this time around but this is not the behavior I was expecting and I've been unable to fix it.

Comment: Could you give more information? What kind of pages, langage, module do you use? It sounds like you miss some handler, but it's hard to say without more info.

Comment: Problem solved. Originally I thought the issue was with all extensions, not just PHP. Purging and re-installing libapache2-mod-php5 straightened everything out. The strange thing was that my phpinfo() page would render, but no other pages. It's seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Next time you ask a question, try to give more info up front, including OS, environment, config files, etc.